# Clear way to setup LSP (vim-lsc) with vim + CMake?

Tags: c++, vim, cmake, static-analysis, clangd

I am trying to set up LSP with vim + cmake. I am using vim-lsc plugin as client and clangd as the server.

Folder structure:

- Test/
- test.cpp
- test.h
- CMakeLists.txt

test.h:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

class Apple {
  public:
    int size;
};

#endif
```

test.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"

int main() {
    Apple apple;

    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(my_test)
add_executable(test test.cpp)
target_include_directories(test PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

~/.vimrc:

```
let g:lsc_server_commands = {'c': 'clangd', 'cpp': 'clangd'}
```

I build with

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

This compiles fine with no errors and warnings.

However, while editing `test.cpp` in vim, vim-lsc shows errors not detecting user defined header files and types defined within them. For example, in the above project, the following two errors are shown:

```
test.cpp|3 col 10 error| 'test.h' file not found [pp_file_not_found]
test.cpp|6 col 5 error| Unknown type name 'Apple' [unknown_typename]
```

How do I set this up so that headers in the project are identified properly?

EDIT: The problem has changed somewhat. I added a compile_commands.json file to the top level directory to no avail. I suspect that it has to do with the way paths are represented in Git Bash on windows.

The compile_commands.json has the inlcude paths like so:

```
-IE:\\C:\\Test
```

If the class is defined in the same file, the lsp protocol seems to be working. Can clang not work with such paths? Could someone shed some light on this?